# Why do $\frac1{n!(n+2)}$ terms add to zero?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

We have a Taylor series expansion:
$$xe^x=x+\frac{x^2}{1!}+\frac{x^3}{2!}+\dots$$

Integrating both sides, we have
$$xe^x-e^x=\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{3\cdot1!}+\frac{x^4}{4\cdot2!}+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}$$

Setting $x$ to $1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!(n+2)}=e-e=0$$

How can a sum of positive numbers be equal to zero?

Comment: The result of the integration is obviously wrong, as $0e^0-e^0\ne 0$. The fix is easy, add the constant $-1$. Now your sum is $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the RHS to be $0$ for $x=0$, we want to integrate the LHS as

$$ \int_0^x te^t \ dt = xe^x - e^x + 1 $$

This gives the right result

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+2)n!} = 1 $$

Your mistake was forgetting the constant of integration
$$ \int xe^x \ dx = xe^x - e^x + C $$

In general, this constant is arbitrary, but when integrating two sides of an equation, care must be taken to maintain the equality.

Answer (score 1):

Note that : $$\quad{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!(n+2)}=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\color{red} {n+1}}{n!'(\color{red} {n+1})(n+2)}=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)!}=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}=\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}=\\\frac{1}{1!}-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\\=1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that indefinite integrations always give a constant. Thus, integrating the LHS, we have $xe^x-e^x + c_1$ (say.)

Similarly on integrating every term of the RHS, there is a constant. Let the sum of all those constants be $C$.

Obviously, $C \neq c_1$. Hence, the sum at $x = 1$ isn't zero.

---

This is confirmed when we expand $xe^x - e^x$ as a Taylor series as we get a $-1$ on the RHS.

So, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n!(n+2)} = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Another way:

$$\dfrac1{(n+2)\cdot n!}=\dfrac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac{n+2-1}{(n+2)!}=\dfrac1{(n+1)!}-\dfrac1{(n+2)!}$$

$$\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!(n+2)}=\dfrac1{1!}-\dfrac1{2!}+\dfrac1{2!}-\dfrac1{3!}+\cdots=?$$